# How do you remove NAs?

Tags: r, dplyr, na.rm

```
penguins %>% 
  select(bill_length_mm) %>% 
filter(!is.na(bill_length_mm)) %>% 
  mean(as.numeric(bill_length_mm), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Error message:  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA[1] NA

Examining the dataset after filtering shows numeric data with no NAs.
Why am I getting this error?  Shouldn't line two or line three of the code remove all NAs?

Thank you.

Comment: `mean(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping `mean` in `summarize`, like

```
penguins %>% 
  select(bill_length_mm) %>% 
filter(!is.na(bill_length_mm)) %>% 
  summarize(mean(as.numeric(bill_length_mm), na.rm=TRUE))
```

This is happening because `mean` is expecting a vector, but you are passing a dataframe (from the pipe).